# Response body in Tobi.js?

Tags: node.js, browser

I'm using https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi, a browser simulator, to test an external web app. I'd like to be able to see the response body returned in the callback.

I understand the normal way node.js server-side apps show body is via `res.on('data')`, but my understanding is that inside the toby browser callback the response is now complete. Yet I can't find a `res.body`, `res.data`, or anything similar. Nor can I find docs on the topic!

```
function(error, response, $){ 
    // Headers are there
    console.log(response.headers;
    // Horrible hack to show body via jquery as response.body and response.data are undefined
    console.log($('body').html());
}
```

Per the above, I can see the document data via jQuery, so it's there. I just can't find it inside response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jQuery usage is the intended way to use tobi. It consumes the response and gives you a `$` to manipulate or examine it.

Comment: Doing some research - that the request has finished etc - makes me inclined to agree. JQuery consumes the response body, everything else you can see in the response.